# No valid responses from any peers while deploying the BNA file with "composer network start"

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

I am following the link: https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/tutorials/deploy-to-fabric-multi-org to deploy bna file in 2 different peers. 
Up to step-16 everything is working fine, but when I am trying to deploy the .bna file getting following error.
After importing the identity cards to composer when I have run "install runtime" command for Org1, it is successfully processed but when I am running for Org2 it is showing "No valid responses from any peers" error. 
Following are the output.

```
amandai@ubuntultop:~/block chain/fabric-samples V1/ess-multipeer-sample/network$ composer network start -c PeerAdmin@amsnetwork-essbbsr -a amsnetwork.bna -o endorsementPolicyFile=endorsement-policy.json -A chinmayak -C chinmayak/admin-pub.pem -A kkumarbabu -C kkumarbabu/admin-pub.pem
Starting business network from archive: amsnetwork.bna
  Business network definition:
  Identifier: amsnetwork@0.2.0-20180102082548
  Description: The Hello World of Hyperledger Composer samples

Processing these Network Admins: 
  userName: chinmayak
  userName: kkumarbabu

✖ Starting business network definition. This may take a minute...
Error: Error trying to instantiate composer runtime. Error: No valid responses from any peers.
Response from attempted peer comms was an error: Error: REQUEST_TIMEOUT
Response from attempted peer comms was an error: Error: REQUEST_TIMEOUT

Command failed
```

Even all the peers are up.

```
amandai@ubuntultop:~/block chain/fabric-samples V1/ess-multipeer-sample/network$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                        COMMAND                     CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                            NAMES
c83e1a245386        hyperledger/fabric-tools     "/bin/bash -c './s..."   6 minutes ago       Up 6 minutes                                                         cli
46bf68ca719e        hyperledger/fabric-peer      "peer node start"        6 minutes ago       Up 6 minutes        0.0.0.0:8051->7051/tcp,  0.0.0.0:8053->7053/tcp   peer0.ezone.esspl.com
2e740ce743fe        hyperledger/fabric-ca        "sh -c 'fabric-ca-..."   6 minutes ago       Up 6 minutes        0.0.0.0:7054->7054/tcp                           ca_peerEssbbsr
cc48b8ee44db        hyperledger/fabric-orderer   "orderer"                6 minutes ago       Up 6 minutes        0.0.0.0:7050->7050/tcp                           orderer.esspl.com
46077fc3888a        hyperledger/fabric-peer      "peer node start"        6 minutes ago       Up 6 minutes        0.0.0.0:7051->7051/tcp, 0.0.0.0:7053->7053/tcp   peer0.essbbsr.esspl.com
3f65239e7315        hyperledger/fabric-ca        "sh -c 'fabric-ca-..."    6 minutes ago       Up 6 minutes        0.0.0.0:8054->7054/tcp                           ca_peerEzone
```

Please help how to resolve this. Thanks

Comment: If the `composer runtime install` fails for Org2 - you need to correct this before moving on to composer network start.

It is likely that you have errors in the connection.json file for org2.

Answer (score 0):

I did the following modification in "peer-base.yaml" file and issue has been resolved.

```
- CORE_VM_DOCKER_HOSTCONFIG_NETWORKMODE=${COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME}_byfn
```

To

```
- CORE_VM_DOCKER_HOSTCONFIG_NETWORKMODE=network_amsnetwork
```

Here "network_amsnetwork" is the network name. You can find your network name by using "docker network ls" command